# Как реализовать методы add у Queue и метод push у Stack

Tags: java, очередь, стек, linked-list

Добрый день сообщество . Задали задание решить . Реализовать контейнеры Queue и Stack на базе Linkedlist . Как работает метод add я знаю т.е добавляем  новый элемент в начало  очереди . А вот как реализовать специфический порядок  никак не получается. Если не трудно напишите реализацию на базе линкед листа двухсвязанного списка . Смотрел реализацию  в самой коллекции , но  почему то она у меня не работает.

```
 private int size = 0;
    private Node<E> first;
    private Node<E> last;
    private int count = 0;

    public SimpleQueue() {
        first = new Node(null, null, last);
        last = new Node(first, null, null);
    }



    private  class Node<E> {
        E item;
        Node<E> next;
        Node<E> prev;

        Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
            this.item = element;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }

    }


    public E  poll() {
        final Node<E> result = first.next;
        return (result.item == null) ? null : helpForPoll(result);
    }

    //метод извлекает иэлемент из головы очереди и возвращает его . удаляет этот элемент или возвращает нул если очередь пустая

    private E helpForPoll(Node<E> value) {
        final E element = value.item;
        first = new Node<>(null, null, first.next.next);
        value.prev = null;
        value.item = null;
        value.next = null;
        size--;
        return element;
    }

    // метод вставляет элемент в конец очереди согласно логике

    public boolean offer(E value) {

        size++;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object value) {

        size++;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        Node<E> temp = first.next;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            temp = getNextElement(temp);
        }
        return temp.item;
    }

    private Node<E> getNextElement(Node<E> value) {
        return value.next;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new Iterator() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return count < size;
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                if (count == size) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                return get(count++);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Так нужно просто понять суть этих структур. Для стека извлечение элемента происходит с того же конца, куда вставляли, а для очереди - с другого конца списка.

Comment: Да я понимаю суть просто я не могу написать код , чтобы в одном случае объекты вставлялись как в очереди , а в другом как стек . Ссылки не могу правильно переопределить . Конструктор у  классов  начальный одинаковый

Comment: public Test {  first = new Node(null, null, last)   last = new Node(first,null,null)  }

Comment: Вставлять одинаково. Не надо код в комментариях, лучше показать его, отредактировав вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю Java в достаточной мере, но список выглядит неработоспособным.

```
    first = new Node(null, null, last);
    last = new Node(first, null, null);
```

Здесь в первой строк создаётся узел со ссылкой next на ёще не существующий last. Её надо поправить после создания last.

Метод вставки в конец (push) не реализован. Он един для стека и очереди и может выглядеть так:

```
 newNode = new Node(last.prev, Data, last);
 last.prev = newNode
 счётчик и чего там ещё обновить
```

Извлечение нужно сделать из начала и с конца. Первое понадобится для очереди, второе для стека.

```
popBegin:
   node = first.next
   if node = last
     return null
   first.next = node.next
   node.next.prev = first
   теперь можно забрать данные и освободить node 

popEnd:
   сделать зеркально по аналогии
```